# How can I iterate through a list of keys and return the respective value in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a list with keys from an array/dictionary:

```
 keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
```

My dict looks like this

```
 {"key1": 
      {
         "key2": 
             {
                "key3": "Value I want to receive"
             }
      }
 }
```

I need a function that returns `dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3]` or "False" if its not valid. For the latter I can use `try, except` I think? I can't figure it out and I don't want to use `eval()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to write any code for it? You say you want to iterate through the keys; do you know how to iterate at all? If you want to get the `dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]` result - supposing it exists - and you have a list like `["key1", "key2", "key3"]` - what will be the first value you get from the list when you iterate? What do you think you should do with that value? Can you think of the code structure to repeat the process?

Comment: "or "False" if its not valid. For the latter I can use try, except I think?" Are you familiar with the `get` method of dictionaries?

Comment: No, I don't know the get-methodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

my_dict = {"key1": 
               {
                   "key2": 
                       {
                           "key3": "Value I want to receive"
                       }
                }
           }

# return the element in case all keys exists or False otherwise
def get_third_key(d, key1, key2, key3):
    if (key1 in d) and (key2 in d.get(key1)) and (key3 in d.get(key1).get(key2)):
        return d.get(key1).get(key2).get(key3)
    return False

# now you can call get_third_key on given arguments
print(get_third_key(my_dict, *keys))
```

Evaluating condintions within `if` statement is according to defenition, which mean they will be evaluated from left to right (hence you don't need `try\except` blocks).

Using `d.get` will cause the `if` statement to fail if `key` is not a key in relevant dictionary, instead of throwing `KeyError` Exception (that can happen while using `[]` operator).

p.s - `*` operator unpacks the `keys` list, and specify each positional parameter in the function.

Comment: Well, this way the list with keys is not iterable..

Comment: The list is iterable by definition. Do you mean you *have to* iterate on list and find the value during iteration? otherwise your question is not clear.

Comment: Well, if I hardcoded the list, I could just hardcode the keys, right? Of course I need to iterate through the keys list.